# Using ZXing Barcode reader in .Net 8 Android

Tags: xamarin.android, maui, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0, zxing.net.mobile

We are updating our mobile app originally developed in Xamarin, but the Upgrade Assistant is of no use, and moving to MAUI and Blazor is a big move instead of just staying with our XAML forms. We have thus created a new project in VS2022 using the Android Application template and .Net 8, and then adding all the existing classes to this project. Most of it is working well so far, the biggest issues being finding NuGet packages that are ready for .Net 8. One of them being the ZXing.Net.Mobile package. We cannot use this package, as it also brings along the V4.Support package, which causes build errors and duplicate declarations for some JAVA classes. Is there a version that we can use in this project? Can we use ZXing.Net.Maui in this project, as it doesn't implement the MauiApp, but still uses the old Xamarin style startup on an Activity? Any other ideas/suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Use the Maui package, that has nothing to do with Blazor